# translating a usual proof into natural deduction.

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I have some trouble with proving stuff with natural deduction formalism.
Let $R$ be a binary relation.
For instance I want to prove
$\phi,\psi \vdash \theta$
Where
$\phi : \forall x \forall y \forall z ((R(x,y) \wedge R(y,z) \rightarrow R(x,z))$. (i.e. $R$ is transitive).
$\psi : \forall x \neg R(x,y)$. (i.e. $R$ is irreflexive).
$\theta : \forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \rightarrow \neg R(y,x))$. (meaning $R$ is asymmetric).

So I first try to make a usual proof :
1)  Assume $R$ is not antisymmetric. So $\exists x \exists y R(x,y)\wedge R(y,x)$.
2)But one assumption is that $R$ is transitive so $\exists x R(x,x)$.
3)$\exists x R(x,x)$ and $\psi$ produce a contradiction $\bot$.

But then I don't get how to translate each step in natural deduction.

**edit**

so fist I assume $\theta$ is wrong so I think I should start by using the classical absurd :

${\phi,\psi,\neg \theta \vdash \bot}$
$\overline{\phi,\psi \vdash \theta}$

then with some steps I don't really know, I should have :

${\phi, \psi, (R(a,b) \wedge R(b,a)) \vdash \bot}$
$\overline{\phi, \psi, \exists x \exists y (R(x,y) \wedge R(y,x)) \vdash \bot}$
. . .

$\overline{\phi,\psi,\neg \theta \vdash \bot}$
$\overline{\phi,\psi \vdash \theta}$

also how do you eliminate the double $\exists$ on the left of the sequent?

Comment: At which step of the translation do you get stuck? Do you know how to work with natural deduction?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Start from assumption 1) : $∃x∃y(R(x,y)∧R(y,x))$ and apply double $\exists$-elim :

> 2) $R(a,b) ∧ R(b,a)$ --- assumed for $\exists$-elim.

From *transitivity* ($\phi$), by $\forall$-elim, we get :

3) $R(a,b) ∧ R(b,a) → R(a,a)$.

Thus, with 2) :

4) $R(a,a)$.

From *irreflexivity* ($\psi$ : you have a typo) we get, by $\forall$-elim :

5) $\lnot R(a,a)$.

Now we have a contradiction : $\bot$ and we can close the double $\exists$-elim deriving :

6) $\bot$.

In this way we have : $\lnot ∃x∃y(R(x,y)∧R(y,x))$.

Now we are left with the boring part : to derive the equivalent $∀x∀y(R(x,y) → ¬R(y,x)$.

Comment: In the deduction tree, are you going from up to down or from down to up (see edit)?

Comment: @roi_saumon - I'm going up-down. From the premises to the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

> also how do you eliminate the double ∃ on the left of the sequent?

Do not even introduce existentials.   You are not dealing with existential witnesses but arbitrary terms.

$\phi,\psi,$ and $\theta$ are each composed only of *universal quantified* statements.   That contraindicates pulling existential rules out of the toolbox.

Rather your proof should be structured around *universal eliminations* and *universal introductions*.   Work entirely with these arbitrary assumptions.

Now, there is a *negation elimination/introduction* involved (a *proof of contradiction*), but that is best placed within the context of those arbitrary assumptions.

Here is the skeleton of the fitch style proof.
$$\def\R{\mathrm R}\fitch{\forall x\forall y\forall z~(x\R y\land y\R z\to x\R z)\\\forall x~\lnot x\R x}{\fitch{[a]}{\fitch{[b]}{\fitch{a\R b}{\fitch{b\R a}{a\R b\land b\R a\\\vdots\quad\text{somehow}\\\bot}\\\lnot b\R a}\\a\R b\to\lnot b\R a}\\\forall y~(a\R y\to \lnot y\R a)}\\\forall x\forall y~(x\R y\to\lnot y\R x)}$$